# Using MVIEWS to take in time data snapshot of tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a requirement where I have to Load data periodically from more than 100 tables of an OLTP oracle database into MS SQL database. In my solution I want to use MVIEWs of these tables with Fast Refresh as the point of data extraction in oracle.

Every time before triggering the data load into MS SQL database I will refresh the MVIEWs to get the data. However have below mentioned doubts:

1) Is there a way through which i can refresh all the MVIEWs at once?

2) How can I ensure that data changes happening during the MVIEW refresh will not be reflected in the refreshed MVIEW. e.g. I started a refresh of all the MVIEWs at 10:00 AM then how can I ensure that no changes happening after 10:00 AM reflects in the refreshed MVIEWs?

3) Is there a better way of achieving this? I don't have the option of using mirror database.

Comment: +1 for a good first question! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_mview.htm#i997194)

1. > list - Comma-delimited list of materialized views that you want to
   >   refresh. ... Alternatively, you may pass in a PL/SQL index-by table of type DBMS_UTILITY.UNCL_ARRAY, where each element is the name of a materialized view.
2. > atomic_refresh - If this parameter is set to true, then the list of materialized views
   >   is refreshed in a single transaction. All of the refreshed
   >   materialized views are updated to a single point in time. If the
   >   refresh fails for any of the materialized views, none of the
   >   materialized views are updated.
3. Maybe flashback query. [Using Oracle Flashback Query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#i1008579) [DBMS_FLASHBACK.ENABLE_AT_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_flashb.htm#i999213).

Comment: Does MVIEW referesh locks the source tables till they are completely refereshed?. If that is so then using it in OLTP system will cause issues .

Comment: @Vishesh Tables need not to be locked to have a consistent state of them, even if that is from the past and not the present. That is what you have undo for.